# Secondary Index in Redis via StackExchange.Redis

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, spring-data-redis

With Spring data redis @indexed I am able to set a index in the Redis.

just defining my domain like this

```
@RedisHash("customer")
    public class Customer extends Serializble{

    @Id
    Private String CustomerId;
    @Indexed
    Private String CustmerName;
    …
    }
```

I am trying to achieve the came with C# StackExchange.Redis. Successfully able to create the Hash

```
IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase(Variables.RedisDatabaseIndex);


db.HashSet(Row.customerId, new HashEntry[] {new HashEntry("customerName", Row.customerName) )
```

The problem is I am not able to create Index similar to the Indexed option in the spring data redis. I tried to get from the stackexchange.redis documentation but couldn't find any solution to this. Any pointers would help

Comment: Did you consider using http://rediSearch.io? see also https://libraries.io/nuget/NRediSearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, SE.Redis simply exposes the core redis commands and primitives. If you know what commands you want to issue: SE.Redis will help you. It *does not*, however, attempt to offer more complex scenarios. You can usually do those things - whether manually of via tools like RediSearch - but: you'll need to figure out that part yourself. When you know what you want to do, SE.Redis will help you ask the server to do it. Either directly, or via wrappers like NRediSearch.

Answer (score 1):

StackExchange.Redis simply wraps [RESP commands](https://redis.io/commands). It doesn't attempt to provide any abstractions on top of that.

Redis itself doesn't have a notion of "secondary indices" - at least not in a way that you might be used to from traditional relational databases. However, it offers a number of data structures that can be used for maintaining what is effectively a secondary index.

I'm not familiar with Spring's Redis client, but in your above example, you would have to manually maintain some form of mapping of customer names to customer ids, e.g. using another hash or one key per name.

If you want to offer some form of search, you might want to look into a [Trigram-based search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigram).

I wrote [an article](https://www.memurai.com/blog/model-hash-attributes-using-secondary-indexes-in-redis-and-memurai) about how to maintain those indices (either via transactions or batch jobs), which you might also find useful. That being said, it mostly focuses on numeric indices, whereas you seem to be looking for some form of search.